# Sequential addition of nested arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, map-function, array.prototype.map

I am trying to add 4 nested arrays with 9 numeric values together in javascript and having issues. They are currently stored like: x = [[Array1(9)], [Array2(9)], [Array3(9)], [Array4(9)]]

I would like "zip" them together and add in the process so adding Array1[0] with Array2-4[0] to all nine values. So each of the four arrays summing up their matching ids.
Arrays look like this:

[1, 2, 4, 3.6, 1.05, 4.65, 1.95, 0.5, 2.5]

[0.432, 0.602, 1.29, 1.146, 0.558, 1.43, 0.686, 0.178, 1.024]

translating to:

[1.432, 2.602, ect...]

I can't seem to get a x.map() function to put them together the way I want.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: if you found any answer please mark it as correct so that users having the similar problem will know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may traverse your outer array with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and loop through nested arrays one by one with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) adding up nested array items to corresponding item of resulting array:

```js
const src = [[1, 2, 4, 3.6, 1.05, 4.65, 1.95, 0.5, 2.5], [0.432, 0.602, 1.29, 1.146, 0.558, 1.43, 0.686, 0.178, 1.024]]
      
      result = src.reduce((r,a) => (a.forEach((n,j) => r[j] = (r[j]||0)+n), r),[])
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using for each for outer and inner array

```js
let arr1 =[ [1, 2, 4, 3.6, 1.05, 4.65, 1.95, 0.5, 2.5],
[0.432, 0.602, 1.29, 1.146, 0.558, 1.43, 0.686, 0.178, 1.024]]
let arr2=[];arr1.forEach( (arr)=> arr.forEach((innerArr,index)=>{
if(!arr2[index])arr2[index]=0;arr2[index]=arr2[index]+innerArr;
}));
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the first array for mapping, add to each value the corresponding values from the other 3 arrays. You can create a function for it for arrays of arbitrary length (see `sumArrays` in the snippet)

```js
const arrays = getData();
let sums = arrays[0].map( (v, i) => v + arrays[1][i] + arrays[2][i] + arrays[3][i] );
let sums2 = sumArrays(arrays);

console.log(sums);
console.log(sums2);

function sumArrays(arrays) {
 const checkLengthEquality = () => {
  let cando = arrays.map(v => v.length);
  return Math.max.apply(null, cando) === Math.min.apply(null, cando);
 };

 if (!checkLengthEquality()) {
  throw Error("Arrays not of equal length");
 }
 
 const sum = (v, i) => {
  let len = arrays.length;
  while(len-- > 1) {
    v += arrays[len][i];
  }
  return v;
 };
 
 return arrays[0].map( (v, i) => sum(v, i) );
}

function getData() {
  return [
    [1, 2, 4, 3.6, 1.05, 4.65, 1.95, 0.5, 2.5], 
    [0.432, 0.602, 1.29, 1.146, 0.558, 1.43, 0.686, 0.178, 1.024],
    [3.1, 2, 4.3, 3.8, 1.5, 6.5, 95, 1.5, 2.5],
    [12, 1, 1.3, 8, 5.3, 6.2, 5, 1, 2.3]
  ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: what if there are lot of inner arrays you cant write arrays[1][i],arrays[2][i],arrays[3][i]...........so on ..there should be innerloop inside map to iterate arrays.length times...thoughts?